# Android: what happens to APP when the revoked permission is granted?

Tags: android

Both android.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION and com.google.android.gms.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION are added in AndroidManifest.xml. After my App is installed and launched, I grant Physical Activity permission and I can use google service to detect activities. Then, I revoke the Physical Activity permission, and switch to the App. The App is restarted by OS. This is OK. However, after I grant the permission again and back to the App, the App knows nothing about the permission change. And the App doesn't restart either.

I tested this in Pixel 3a (os 12) and Pixel 6 (os 14 Beta)

Will the App be killed and restarted once the revoked permission is granted again?

Answer (score 0):

> Will the App be killed and restarted once the revoked permission is granted again?

No, process termination only occurs when permissions are revoked.